# Error Sending Email using smtp.office365.com and PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, outlook, syntax-error, sendmail

Please help, send email error using SMTP Outlook 365.
previously it was still able to run, but suddenly an error.

these my code

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'XXX@XXXX.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '@@@@@@@@@';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
        $config['starttls'] = FALSE;
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '5';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['charset']='iso-8859-1';  
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['newline']="\r\n"; 
        $config['crlf']= "\r\n";    
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    //Email content
    $htmlContent = 'XXX';
    $htmlContent .= 'XXX';
    $this->email->to('XXX@XXXX.com');
    $this->email->from('XXXXX@XXXXX.com','MyWebsite');
    $this->email->subject('How to send email via SMTP server in CodeIgniter');
    $this->email->message($htmlContent);
    //Send email
    $this->email->send();
    if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "Email sent!!"; 
        } else {
            echo "Email is not sent!!";
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
}
```

and these an error result
[image]

Comment: Not your current issue but you won't want `$this->email->send()` twice, that would send the email twice

Comment: @user3783243  it's just typo, if the code removed, still the same error

Comment: @asgart3a Any luck getting it work? I got the same issue